# In Visual Studio 2019, how to GIT commit only specific files (only .vb or .sln or .vbxproj files)?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, git-commit

Today, I want to Commit my work to my local GIT repository from Visual Studio 2019.

From `Solution Explorer`, I active `GIT` context menu and `Commit` action and a new `Modification Git` panel is displayed in which **ALL** modified and added files are displayed.

[image]

I can see a lot of files with a lot of types

```
.vb
.sln
.dll
.db
.dia
.cache
.pdb
.png
```

But I'm only interesting to commit `.vb`, `.sln` and `.vbxprog` file's types.

In Visual Studio, how can'I limit my commit to only these files ?

How can I do same thing for directory so that `Release` or `Debug` folders are never commited ?

Can I do all theses actions in Visual Studio level ?

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- either filter the list (`*.vb` in the `filter` field), to add only those files;
- or [switch to command-line](https://itsnotbugitsfeature.com/2019/11/08/git-command-line-in-visual-studio/) and `git add *.vb`.

> How can I do same thing for directory so that Release or Debug folders are never commited?

In command-line:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git rm --cached -r Debug/
git rm --cached -r Release/
echo Debug/>>.gitignore
echo Release/>>.gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Ignore Debug and Release folders"
```

You don't need the `git rm` steps if no files in `Debug/` or `Release/` were ever tracked before.
But you need to add them to a `.gitignore` file.

Then you can switch back to Visual Studio: those two folders won't show up anymore.

Comment: Check first if those folders are still displayed in command line with a git status.

Comment: Sorry, but I have deleted previous/first comment because I'm not sure to have written correct folder. Now, I'm sure that my folder is correct and deleted comment was correct.

Comment: I will search later your proposal but thanks for your help.